# Istio Traffic Splitting Not Using Weight Properly

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, istio, envoyproxy, kind

I am using the default bookinfo application https://istio.io/docs/examples/bookinfo/ and trying to test split traffic with the reviews service. Kiali is showing the split and everything seems to be configured correctly but its still doing a round robin. If I remove all virtual services and destination rules, the app works as normally expected.

```
# Source: bookinfo/templates/destination-rule-all.yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: productpage
spec:
  host: productpage
  subsets:
  - name: v1
    labels:
      version: v1
---
# Source: bookinfo/templates/destination-rule-all.yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: ratings
spec:
  host: ratings
  subsets:
  - name: v1
    labels:
      version: v1
  - name: v2
    labels:
      version: v2
  - name: v2-mysql
    labels:
      version: v2-mysql
  - name: v2-mysql-vm
    labels:
      version: v2-mysql-vm
---
# Source: bookinfo/templates/destination-rule-all.yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: details
spec:
  host: details
  subsets:
  - name: v1
    labels:
      version: v1
  - name: v2
    labels:
      version: v2
---
# Source: bookinfo/templates/destination-rule-all.yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: reviews
spec:
  host: reviews
  subsets:
  - name: v1
    labels:
      version: v1
  - name: v2
    labels:
      version: v2
  - name: v3
    labels:
      version: v3
---
# Source: bookinfo/templates/bookinfo-gateway.yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: bookinfo-gateway
  chart: bookinfo-0.1.2
  release: bookinfo
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default controller
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
---
# Source: bookinfo/templates/bookinfo-gateway.yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: bookinfo
  chart: bookinfo-0.1.2
  release: bookinfo
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - bookinfo-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        exact: /productpage
    - uri:
        prefix: /static
    - uri:
        exact: /login
    - uri:
        exact: /logout
    - uri:
        prefix: /api/v1/products
    route:
    - destination:
        host: productpage
        port:
          number: 9080
---
# Source: bookinfo/templates/virtual-service-all-v1.yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: productpage
spec:
  hosts:
  - productpage
  gateways:
  - bookinfo-gateway
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: productpage
        subset: v1
---
# Source: bookinfo/templates/virtual-service-all-v1.yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: reviews
spec:
  hosts:
  - reviews
  gateways:
  - bookinfo-gateway
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: reviews
        subset: v1
      weight: 100
    - destination:
        host: reviews
        subset: v2
      weight: 0
    - destination:
        host: reviews
        subset: v3
      weight: 0
---
# Source: bookinfo/templates/virtual-service-all-v1.yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: ratings
spec:
  hosts:
  - ratings
  gateways:
  - bookinfo-gateway
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: ratings
        subset: v1
---
# Source: bookinfo/templates/virtual-service-all-v1.yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: details
spec:
  hosts:
  - details
  gateways:
  - bookinfo-gateway
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: details
        subset: v1

# Source: bookinfo/templates/reviews-v1-deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: reviews-v1
  labels:
    chart: bookinfo-0.1.2
    release: bookinfo
    app: reviews
    version: v1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: reviews
      release: bookinfo
      version: v1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: reviews
        release: bookinfo
        version: v1
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: bookinfo-reviews
      containers:
      - name: reviews
        image: myhub/istio/examples-bookinfo-reviews-v1:1.15.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        env:
        - name: LOG_DIR
          value: "/tmp/logs"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9080
        volumeMounts:
        - name: tmp
          mountPath: /tmp
        - name: wlp-output
          mountPath: /opt/ibm/wlp/output
      volumes:
      - name: wlp-output
        emptyDir: {}
      - name: tmp
        emptyDir: {}
---
# Source: bookinfo/templates/reviews-v2-deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: reviews-v2
  labels:
    chart: bookinfo-0.1.2
    release: bookinfo
    app: reviews
    version: v2
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: reviews
      release: bookinfo
      version: v2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: reviews
        release: bookinfo
        version: v2
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: bookinfo-reviews
      containers:
      - name: reviews
        image: myhub/istio/examples-bookinfo-reviews-v2:1.15.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        env:
        - name: LOG_DIR
          value: "/tmp/logs"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9080
        volumeMounts:
        - name: tmp
          mountPath: /tmp
        - name: wlp-output
          mountPath: /opt/ibm/wlp/output
      volumes:
      - name: wlp-output
        emptyDir: {}
      - name: tmp
        emptyDir: {}
---
# Source: bookinfo/templates/reviews-v3-deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  metadata:
  name: reviews-v3
  labels:
    chart: bookinfo-0.1.2
    release: bookinfo
    app: reviews
    version: v3
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: reviews
      release: bookinfo
      version: v3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: reviews
        release: bookinfo
        version: v3
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: bookinfo-reviews
      containers:
      - name: ratings
        image: myhub/istio/examples-bookinfo-reviews-v3:1.15.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        env:
        - name: LOG_DIR
          value: "/tmp/logs"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9080
        volumeMounts:
        - name: tmp
          mountPath: /tmp
        - name: wlp-output
          mountPath: /opt/ibm/wlp/output
      volumes:
      - name: wlp-output
        emptyDir: {}
      - name: tmp
        emptyDir: {}
---
```

Environment

kind v0.7.0 go1.13.6 linux/amd64

K8s  v1.18.1 v1.17.0

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce your problem on gke with istio 1.5.2 and everything works fine.

---

I followed istio [bookinfo documentation](https://istio.io/docs/examples/bookinfo/)

```
kubectl apply -f samples/bookinfo/platform/kube/bookinfo.yaml
kubectl apply -f samples/bookinfo/networking/bookinfo-gateway.yaml
```

As mentioned [here](https://istio.io/docs/examples/bookinfo/#apply-default-destination-rules)

### Apply default destination rules

> Before you can use Istio to control the Bookinfo version routing, you need to define the available versions, called subsets, in destination rules.
>
> Run the following command to create default destination rules for the Bookinfo services:
>
> If you did not enable mutual TLS, execute this command:
>
> Choose this option if you are new to Istio and are using the demo configuration profile.

```
$ kubectl apply -f samples/bookinfo/networking/destination-rule-all.yaml
```

> If you did enable mutual TLS, execute this command:

```
$ kubectl apply -f samples/bookinfo/networking/destination-rule-all-mtls.yaml
```

> Wait a few seconds for the destination rules to propagate.
>
> You can display the destination rules with the following command:

```
$ kubectl get destinationrules -o yaml
```

---

### Apply your virtual service for reviews

**Examples**

Traffic only for subset v1.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: reviews
spec:
  hosts:
  - reviews
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: reviews
        subset: v1
```

Traffic only for subset v2.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: reviews
spec:
  hosts:
  - reviews
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: reviews
        subset: v2
```

50/50 weight traffic for subset v2 and v3.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: reviews
spec:
  hosts:
  - reviews
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: reviews
        subset: v2
      weight: 50
    - destination:
        host: reviews
        subset: v3
      weight: 50
```

100/0/0 weight traffic for subset v1,v2 and v3.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: reviews
spec:
  hosts:
  - reviews
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: reviews
        subset: v2
      weight: 100
    - destination:
        host: reviews
        subset: v3
      weight: 0
    - destination:
        host: reviews
        subset: v1
      weight: 0
```

---

With virtual service only for subset v1 Kiali shows traffic goes only to v1

[image]

Istio productpage doesn't show the stars, so it's review v1.

[image]

---

There is documentation about [weight-based routing](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/traffic-shifting/#apply-weight-based-routing) for reviews.

Comment: So strange, I updated my post with pics from Kiali. It's showing everything is correctly configured, but when I refresh the bookinfo app I get red, black and no stars. I even tried deleting all virtual services and destination rules and the app still works normally. Seems to be traffic isnt be forced through the proxy

Comment: That's weird. Is your istio deployed in istio-system namespace? What is your istio version?

Comment: Very strange. Version 1.5.1 and yes its in the istio-system namespace but bookinfo is in its own namespace but ingress is working. I am also running my environment locally via Kind, so could be a defect with the environment.